# Control not going inside jquery function

Tags: jquery

```
@model DynamicRowAdd.Models.Test

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myButton").click(function () {
            alert('hi');
            // Create elements dynamically
            var newRow = "<tr><td>'@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Id, new { @Value = "1" })'</td><td>'@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @Value = "Abcd" })'</td></tr>";
            alert(newRow);
            // Add the new dynamic row after the last row
            $('#myTable tr:last').after(newRow);
        });

    });


</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Id, new { @Value = "1" })
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name, new { @Value = "Abcd" })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id="myButton">Add New Row</button>
```

The above code when i try to run, I get the hi as alert. The following code is when the button is clicked which is not firing. the control is not going inside the function. Why.? I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Wrap your code inside ready handler...

Comment: @BhojendraSah : Not working , see my edit.

Comment: copy your html code in question.

Comment: Where is `myButton` id?

Comment: @Sadikhasan : When I remove everything after the alert it works. If i add the code after alert it doe not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use append method no need to specify any tr.. if u want to insert tr at beggining use prepend()

```
$('#myTable').append(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Write your code here

});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuq4dk3e/1/)**